# Setting up lwm2m-node-lib to FIWARE platform

Tags: fiware

Having reached a stumbling block with my wakaama LWM2M implementation for couple of weeks, as I reported in [#154](https://github.com/telefonicaid/lightweightm2m-iotagent/issues/154) I have no option than to try using `telefonica lwm2m-node-lib` instead.

To make my point clear again, I have already IOTA, Orion, MongoDB, Cygnus all working fine. It is my client implementation that isn't sending measure to IOTA despite being able to connect. The scenario I want is `LWM2M -> IOTA -> Orion -> Cygnus -> MongoDB`.

**My issue now:** I want have a precise explanation of configuration I need to do to have `lwm2m-node-lib implementation` work here, for instance where to input the server IP to connect to (where my FIWARE is running), which file to edit etc. I already picked a new device to use, keeping aside the other.

My docker-compose file below:

```
version: "3.1"

services:

 mongo:
   image: mongo:3.4
   hostname: mongo
   container_name: fiware-mongo
   ports:
     - "27017:27017"
   networks:
     - default
   command: --nojournal

 orion:
   image: fiware/orion
   hostname: orion
   container_name: fiware-orion
   depends_on:
     - mongo
   networks:
     - default
   ports:
     - "1026:1026"
   expose:
     - "1026"
   command: -dbhost mongo -logLevel DEBUG

 lightweightm2m-iotagent:
    image: telefonicaiot/lightweightm2m-iotagent
    hostname: idas
    container_name: fiware-iotagent
    depends_on:
     - mongo
    networks:
     - default
    expose:
     - "4041"
     - "5684"
    ports:
     - "4041:4041"
     - "5684:5684/udp"
    environment:
     - "IOTA_CB_HOST=orion"
     - "IOTA_CB_PORT=1026"
     - "IOTA_NORTH_PORT=4041"
     - "IOTA_REGISTRY_TYPE=mongodb"
     - "IOTA_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG"
     - "IOTA_TIMESTAMP=true"
     - "IOTA_MONGO_HOST=mongo"
     - "IOTA_MONGO_PORT=27017"
     - "IOTA_MONGO_DB=lwm2miotagent"
     - "IOTA_HTTP_PORT=5684"
     - "IOTA_PROVIDER_URL=http://lightweightm2m-iotagent:4041"

 cygnus:
    image: fiware/cygnus-ngsi:latest
    hostname: cygnus
    container_name: fiware-cygnus
    depends_on:
     - mongo
    networks:
     - default
    expose:
     - "5080"
    ports:
     - "5050:5050"
     - "5080:5080"
    environment:
     - "CYGNUS_MONGO_HOSTS=mongo:27017"
     - "CGYNUS_LOG_LEVEL_=DEBUG"
     - "CYGNUS_SERVICE_PORT=5050"
     - "CYGNUS_API_PORT=5080"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to:

https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/lightweightm2m-iotagent/

There you have a very good explanation in how to use the IOTA-LWM2M docker, along with configuration examples to run it with Orion.

Comment: I hold on to see if https://github.com/telefonicaid/lightweightm2m-iotagent/issues/154 could be resolved.